# Flutter not running on Android Emulator with Java 16

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

I'm having trouble running the basic Flutter Template App on Android emulator on MacOS M1

- I've installed the right emulator I think

[image: Android emulator AVD Manager]

It opens correctly

[image: Emulator works]

but when I try to run `flutter run` on it I get the following error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/user/flutter_counter_app/android/build.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file '/Users/user/flutter_counter_app/android/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 60

  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60

...

  1 error

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                           2 928ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Everything works on iOS simulator but I'd like to get Android emulator running my Apps too..

```
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 2.9.0-0.1.pre, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-arm)
    • Flutter version 2.9.0-0.1.pre at /Users/user/FlutterSDK/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 8f1f9c10f0 (4 weeks ago), 2021-12-14 13:41:48 -0800
    • Engine revision 234aca678a
    • Dart version 2.16.0 (build 2.16.0-80.1.beta)
    • DevTools version 2.9.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at:
      /Users/user/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/azul-16.0.1/Contents/Home
      /bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu16.30+19-CA (build 16.0.1+9)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.32.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

Comment: You can put the code of this file: '/Users/user/flutter_counter_app/android/build.gradle'

Comment: sorry ? didn't understand

Comment: Show me the file inside android dir (file '/Users/user/flutter_counter_app/android/build.gradle')

Comment: I've added thank you  I think the issue might come from how I setup my Java version or emulator ? since this is a brand new flutter project : /

Comment: Try this > Replace this line (classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0') for this (classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0') in the build.gradle, after that replace in gradle dir (gradle-wrapper.properties file) your distribution url for this (distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8-all.zip)

Comment: I've follow your instructions I get new error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/E26BA.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240899/discussion-between-sunshine-and-felipe-vergara).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks to Felipe Vergara

-> Had to downgrade Java JDK version by going inside Android Studio - `File`-> `Project Structure` from `16.0` to `11`

[image: Project Structure]

and download a new Java JDK

- then delete the version which was to high in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`
- in root directory I updated the export `JAVA_HOME=` path
- closed Android Studio and restart Terminal
- Run `flutter doctor -v`

now run `flutter run` in your Android Emulator it should work !

Answer (score 0):

For Mac m1 Silicon chip you need to do some extra modification. Just go to your terminal and try this command:

```
$ sudo softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```